# Completely cutting silence out of an audio file

Tags: audio, audacity

I record lecture notes, and they contain giant pauses filled with white noise. Is there some way I can get rid of those passages completely? Using Audacity, I can reduce the white noise (i.e. turn it into silence), but what I'd like to do is crop those bits out from the file so I don't have to play "hunt for the lecture".

Comment: Manually or automatically?

Comment: Automatically. Manually would be too slow.

Answer (score 10):

Try [this](http://audacity.238276.n2.nabble.com/remove-silences-tp293043p293044.html), assuming you can use a sufficiently recent (post 2007, unstable) version of audacity.

Summary of the suggestion, as requested by @slhck:

1. Obtain a version of Audacity later than version 1.3.3. The stable version of Audacity is from 2006, and does not contain the same functionality as the more recent preview releases.
2. Open the file you want to remove the whitespace from.
3. Go to **Effect** > **Truncate Silence**.
4. Set **Min silence duration** and **Max silence duration** to the same value, the length of the longest pauses you want to keep, probably at least a few hundred ms.
5. Set **Threshold for silence** to the threshold you want for detecting silence. You'll probably have to fiddle a bit with this unless you have somehow blanked the silences completely.

The effect is described [here](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/truncate_silence.html)

Comment: Could you maybe summarize the steps here? That would be great.

Answer (score 6):

I have gaps in my interned steaming recordings due to buffering. I found that they can all be automatically closed by using the Effect > Truncate Silence method. I set the duration to 0.1 seconds for detection with a level of -60db and the output duration to 0. Works perfectly.